# Slash Command Feature implement to bot in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So as Discord officially announced the public beta of slash commands for Bots I am just wondering how I can implement them (so your bot's command is in the / menu) if you can. Best option would be to keep the discord.Client so not switching to bot.command. I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Not possible, even if you switched to `commands.Bot` it won't be possible as discord.py doesn't support slash commands yet

Comment: Ok, thanks for Feedback, probably then gonna come with the next update or something, let's see

Comment: I know that Danny (the creator of the library) is working on them, but I doubt they will come fast, there's an unofficial extension that does support slash commands, [link here](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/), but you have to sadly move to `commands.Bot`

Comment: Kay, thanks for the information, gonna see what I'm doing.